# Stop TLS certificates to be automatically recreated by cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I was investigating certain things things about `cert-manager`.

`TLS certificates` are automatically recreated by cert-manager.

I need to somehow **deregister a domain / certificate** from being regenerated. I guess I would need to tell cert-manager not to take care about a given domain anymore.

I do not have any clue how to do that right now. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you delete the `Certificate` custom resource related to your domain?

Comment: This library deletes  Secret object on kubernetes which contains data about the certificate.. @whites11

Comment: There is a big difference between the TLS secret and the `Certificate` CR. Let me explain it in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cert-manager` is an application implemented using the [operator pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/).

In one sentence, it watches for a `Custom Resource` (`CR` for short) named `Certificate` in the Kubernetes API and it creates and updates `Secrets` resources to store certificate data.

If you delete the `Secret` resource but don't delete the `Certificate` CR, `cert-manager` will recreate the secret for you.

The right way of "deregister a domain" or to better say it "make cert-manager not generate a certificate for a domain any more" is to delete the `Certificate` CR related to your domain.

To get a list of all the `Certificate` CRs in your cluster you can use `kubectl`

```
kubectl get certificate -A
```

When you found the `Certificate` related to the domain you want to delete, simply delete it

```
kubectl -n <namespace> delete certificate <certificate name>
```

Once you deleted the certificate CR, you might also want to delete the `Secret` containing the TLS cert one more time. This time `cert-manager` will not recreate it.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot @whites11

Comment: Also is there a way to integrate this via API call. I have a call in my PHP project so I am looking a way to via HTTP request? @whites11

Comment: More precisely I want to trigger kubectl -n <namespace> delete certificate <certificate name> command via HTTP request? @whites11

Comment: This is an HTTP API so as long as the PHP process has access to the API server than you can for sure. Maybe look at some client libraries https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

Comment: This is the library I am using: https://github.com/allansun/kubernetes-php-client @whites11

Comment: Sure you totally can do it (not sure about the library support).
If you have trouble I suggest opening another question on SO.

Comment: How can this be 'un-done'? Can't get it to generate it at all anymore

Comment: You have to recreate the certificate CR